# How to provide the array objects of one event handler to another event handler as input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This is the click event. It has the Array Objects and i want to provide these objects to another event handler. How is this possible?

```
$("#newQuiz_div #modalbody #next").click(function(){
    var qno=$("#question").val();
    var groupname=$("#groupname").val();
    var duration=$("#duration").val();

    var ht='';
    qno++;
    $("#question").val(qno);
    $("#nextQuestion").removeClass("hide");
    ht+=$("#nextQuestion ul").html();
    ht+=('<li>'+qno+'<i class=icon-edit></i><i class=icon-remove></i></li>');
    $("#nextQuestion ul").html(ht);
    //$("#text").val(" ");
    alert("helooo");
    alert(qno);

    var questionNo=new Array(10);
    var qType=new Array(10);
    var text=new Array(10);
    var Coption=new Array(10);
    var CoptionM=new Array(10);

    var qn=0;
    var q=0,qt=0;
    var cop=0,copm=0;

    if($("#qType").val()==2)
    {
        alert("hiii");
        questionNo[qn]=$("#question").val();
        qType[qt]=$("#qType").val();
        text[q]=$("#text1").val();
        CoptionM[copm]=$("#cOptionM").val();
        alert("Question type:"+questionNo[qn]);
        alert("Question type:"+qType[qt]);
        alert("Question :"+text[q]);
        alert("Answer :"+CoptionM[copm]);

        qn++;
        qt++;
        q++;
        copm++;
        $("#text1").val(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("nooo");
        questionNo[qn]=$("#question").val();
        qType[qt]=$("#qType").val();
        text[q]=$("#text").val();
        Coption[cop]=$("#cOption").val();
        alert("Question type:"+questionNo[qn]);
        alert("Question type:"+qType[qt]);
        alert("Question :"+text[q]);
        alert("Answer :"+Coption[cop]);

        qn++;
        qt++;
        q++;
        cop++;
        $("#text").val(" ");
    }

});
```

I want to add another event handler named `$("#btnSave").click(function(){});`

How this Event can access the Array objects created in above Event handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the arrays in both scopes by declaring them outside of the `click` `callback` functions like so. See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9cm2/1/

```
$(function () {
   var questionNo=new Array(10);

  // bind first callback
  $("#clickme").click(function () {
      console.log('first callback', questionNo);
      questionNo[0] = 'foo';
  });

  $("#clickme").click(function () {
     console.log('second callback', questionNo);
  });
});
```

Comment: i want to access the values that i have set in cick one ..it creates a problem only last index value it acess..others are no